# Excel VBA read cell comment

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a code to check if an Excel cell contain a specific threaded comment,

I can't understand why the first code gives me the error

> "Object variable or With block variable not set"

```
Sub test()
    Dim R As Range
    Set R = Range("E10:E205")

    For Each R In R.Cells
        If R.CommentThreaded.Text = "3" Then
                MsgBox (R.Address)
        End If
    Next R
End Sub
```

while this code works fine:

```
Sub test()
    Dim R As Range
    Set R = Range("E10:E205")

    For Each R In R.Cells
        If Not R.CommentThreaded Is Nothing Then
            If R.CommentThreaded.Text = "3" Then
                MsgBox (R.Address)
            End If
        End If
    Next R
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the the cell `R` has no `CommentThreaded` object. Then of course a non-existing `R.CommentThreaded` cannot have a `.Text` property.

That is why you first need to check if `R.CommentThreaded` contains any comment object

```
If Not R.CommentThreaded Is Nothing Then
```

before you can use its `.Text` property.

---

Off topic:

In `MsgBox (R.Address)` you should remove the parenthesis `MsgBox R.Address` unless you really want to switch from submitting the argument as `ByRef` to submitting it `ByVal`.

```
Answer = MsgBox(R.Address)   'parentheses needed because = is used
Call MsgBox(R.Address)       'parentheses needed because 'Call' is used
MsgBox R.Address             'don't use perenthesis without =
```

but here the parenthesis do something completely different (note the extra space!):

```
MsgBox (R.Address)            'parenthesis here force ByVal!
      ^
      | Extra space!
```