# Reading Excel cell comments gives VBA error

Tags: excel, vba, comments

I'm trying to read all the comments from a large excel table into an array, but it stalls at the line setting commentArray(a) with this:

Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set

Here is the relevant bit of my macro:

```
For r = 3 To compListRow  'read all records for this day into array
                Workbooks(logname).Sheets(sheetname).Activate
                a = a + 1
                If Cells(r, "AL").Value = "y" Then 'check species is visible
                    speciesArray(a) = Worksheets(sheetname).Cells(r, "A").Value
                    countArray(a) = Worksheets(sheetname).Cells(r, c).Value
                    commentArray(a) = Worksheets(sheetname).Cells(r, c).Comment.Text
                Else
                    a = a - 1
                End If
            Next r 'until finished species rows for this day
```

Is it because I'm using Cells rather than Range?

Comment: What is `compListRow` and how is it qualified?  Why are you using `.Activate`?  I suspect your variables are not referring to what you think they are.

Comment: Try this....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60757377/excel-vba-read-cell-comment

Comment: Short answer is (probably), If you hit a cell without a comment, your code will throw an error.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @Christofer Weber in the comment, the problem can arise if there are cells without comment.
To avoid that, check if the comment is present before copying it:

```
If Not Worksheets(sheetname).Cells(r, c).Comment is Nothing Then
    commentArray(a) = Worksheets(sheetname).Cells(r, c).Comment.Text
End if
```

Comment: Thanks to Christofer Weber and SevC_10, that was the key to it. All fine now.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error on `.Comment.Text`, try `.CommentThreaded.Text` instead.

Also, there's no reason to `Activate` the `Workbooks(logname).Sheets(sheetname)`, if for some reason you do need to refer to this worksheet you can use the `With` statement.

***Modified Code***

```
With Workbooks(logname).Sheets(sheetname)
    For r = 3 To compListRow  'read all records for this day into array
        If Cells(r, "AL").Value = "y" Then 'check species is visible
            a = a + 1
            speciesArray(a) = Worksheets(sheetname).Cells(r, "A").Value
            countArray(a) = Worksheets(sheetname).Cells(r, c).Value
            commentArray(a) = Worksheets(sheetname).Cells(r, c).CommentThreaded.Text
        End If
    Next r 'until finished species rows for this day
End With
```

Comment: I had already tried .CommentThreaded.Text, that simply gave a different error (438 - 'Object doesn't support this property or method'). Also I use Activate because I am reading from this spreadsheet and writing to another, but as you indicate I should have put the statement before the 'For' statement.