# Summarizing Row Data and Comments in Another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to take horizontal data from one sheet and summarize it vertically in another sheet.

The first sheet tallies student names vertically and corresponding data horizontally.
The second sheet will be a temporary report showing just one student's data.

I studied many posts, including:
[Excel VBA read cell comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60757377/excel-vba-read-cell-comment)
[Reading Excel cell comments gives VBA error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66852586/reading-excel-cell-comments-gives-vba-error)

Desired functionality:

- Click in an even cell in col A to run a report of student data.
- Each student's data occupies 2 rows, the even row and the next odd row.
- Loop through each cell in the range of the 2 rows, placing the data in another temporary sheet.
- Student names are in column B.
- Student data starts in column E and expands columns to the right as needed.
- Many of the data cells contain threaded comments, and these comments need to be included but placed vertically into cells.

The code is able to insert the new, temp worksheet and insert the headings (Number, Author, Date, Text), but no cell data and threaded comments data are transferred.

```vb
Sub ListCommentsThreaded()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim myCmt As CommentThreaded
    Dim curwks As Worksheet
    Dim newwks As Worksheet
    Dim currng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cmtCount As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set curwks = ActiveSheet
    
    'THE CURRENT RANGE WILL BE A SET OF TWO ROWS, STARTING IN COL B
    'THE RANGE LENGTH (# COLUMNS) WILL VARY PER STUDENT, ARBITRARILY SET AT 90 COLS
    'MANY OF THE CELLS IN THE RANGE WILL HAVE THREADED COMMENTS, STARTING IN COLUMN E
    'SOME CELLS MAY LACK COMMENTS
    
    'Set currng = curwks.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(1, 90))
    Set currng = curwks.Range(ActiveCell.Resize(1, 90).Address)
    
    Set newwks = wb.Worksheets.Add
    
    newwks.Range("B5:E5").Value = Array("Number", "Author", "Date", "Text")
          
    curwks.Activate
    i = 0
    For Each cell In currng.Cells
        If Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
            With cell
                If Not .CommentThreaded Is Nothing Then
                    With newwks
                        i = i + 1
                        On Error Resume Next
                        .Cells(i, 1).Value = i - 1
                        .Cells(i, 2).Value = myCmt.Author.Name
                        .Cells(i, 3).Value = myCmt.Date
                        .Cells(i, 4).Value = myCmt.Text
                    End With
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next cell
    
    With newwks
        .Columns(4).ColumnWidth = 50
        .Columns.AutoFit
        With .Cells
            .EntireRow.AutoFit
            .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
            .WrapText = True
        End With
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You never set `myCmt` to anything...

Comment: Thanks Tim. I will examine it more. What's confusing me is how to extract the contents of the cells as well as the contents of comments, and include both on the report sheet, perhaps beside each other in adjacent columns.

Comment: Do your comments have multiple entries you need to capture (ie. a comment and then one or more replies, possibly from different authors?)  How should those additional entries be recorded?

Comment: Thanks Tim. No, we're not using the threaded feature of comments. I don't anticipate that we will. So currently, there is normally only one comment per cell. Sometimes us teachers will forget a comment. Most of the cells though have data and then 1 comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```vb
Sub ListCommentsThreaded()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    Dim curwks As Worksheet, newwks As Worksheet
    Dim currng As Range, rw As Range, cell As Range
    Dim i As Long, cmtCount As Long, v
    
    Set curwks = ActiveSheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Set currng = ActiveCell.Resize(2, 90)
    
    Set newwks = wb.Worksheets.Add
    Set rw = newwks.Range("B5:G5")
    rw.Value = Array("Number", "Address", "Cell Value", _
                     "Cmt. Author", "Cmt. Date", "Cmt. Text")
    
    i = 0
    For Each cell In currng.Cells
        v = cell.Value
        If Not IsNumeric(v) Then
            i = i + 1
            Set rw = rw.Offset(1)
            rw.Cells(1).Value = i
            rw.Cells(2).Value = cell.Address(False, False)
            rw.Cells(3).Value = v
            'does this cell have a comment?
            If Not cell.CommentThreaded Is Nothing Then
                With cell.CommentThreaded
                    rw.Cells(4).Value = .Author.Name
                    rw.Cells(5).Value = .Date
                    rw.Cells(6).Value = .Text
                End With
            End If 'has comment
        End If     'not numeric
    Next cell
    
    With newwks
        .Columns(4).ColumnWidth = 50
        .Columns.AutoFit
        With .Cells
            .EntireRow.AutoFit
            .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
            .WrapText = True
        End With
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much Tim. Must be nice to be able to do this in minutes instead of days...